# Is there any way to allow pycharm autocomplete the function arguments?

Tags: pycharm

The pycharm ctrl+p can only show the argument tip. Is there any way can let the pycharm automatically inject all the arguments (with default argument name) into code as pydev?

Answer (score 0):

I am using PyCharm community edition 2016.2.1 on Linux and the best I could find (after searching for a while on the topic) is to use the same as in Eclipse: Ctrl + Space. This creates a drop down menu containing all the function arguments which allows you to select the ones you need. Unfortunately, the drop down menu also contains non functions arguments entries but typically the arguments show up at the top. Note however that arguments are not always in the right order. So not a great solution but this is is what I'm using now.